# Getting values from yml configuration to dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I got class:

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "${service.name}", targetNamespace = "${service.namespace}", wsdlLocation = "${service.wsdlLocation}")
public class ExampleService extends Service {
    @Value("${service.wsdlLocation}")
    private static String wsdlLocation;
}
```

It is a part of the mvn project which I compile and use from my local maven repo as a dependency to my other spring-boot app, which have configuration yml:

```
service:
  name: name
  namespace: namespace
  wsdlLocation: wsdlLocation
```

Is there a way that this ExampleService class will use configuration of the "parent" project?

EDIT:

Two answers appearred, but I felt I did not ask question clearly. What I want to do now is to use class ExampleService in my "parent" project and make it see configuration from that parent project. So far when for example I write in parent project code like:

```
ExampleService exampleService = new ExampleService();
System.out.println(exampleService.getWsdlLocation());
```

Null is printed. So I'm looking for some solution to that.

EDIT 2:
Here are my classes.
Parent project:

```
package com.example.kris.parentservice;

import com.example.kris.childservice.ExampleService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

//    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;
    @Value(value = "${service.wsdlLocation}")
    private String wsdlLocation;

    @GetMapping(value = "/example")
    public void example() {
        exampleService = new ExampleService();
        System.out.println("ExampleService field: " + exampleService.getWsdlLocation());
        System.out.println("@Value: " + wsdlLocation);
    }
}
```

Child project:

```
package com.example.kris.childservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class ExampleService {
    @Value("${service.wsdlLocation}")
    private String wsdlLocation;

    public String getWsdlLocation() {
        return wsdlLocation;
    }
}
```

And output after running parent controller:

```
ExampleService field: null
@Value:test.wsdl.location
```

Comment: It appears like yml is not loaded can you add the same property in application.properties to ensure this one is picked.

Comment: Yaml is loaded, I can use other values in classes which are created in parent project. The problem is with the classes from project loaded as dependency.

Comment: @KrzysztofTkacz whenever you edit question try leaving a comment to people who answered,  I didn't notice edit, editing my answer as code is getting messy in comments

Answer (score 0):

YamlPropertySourceLoader can be helpful in spring boot app inject a bean like this

```
@Bean
public PropertySource<?> yamlPropertySourceLoader() throws IOException {
    YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    PropertySource<?> applicationYamlPropertySource = loader.load("application.yml",
            new ClassPathResource("application.yml"), "default");
    return applicationYamlPropertySource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
>   designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order: [Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

base on same you can decide which properties are going to be in effect. **If a property key is duplicated, the last declared file will ‘win’ and override.**

> 1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory    (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
>
>    2. @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
>    3. properties attribute on your tests. Available on @SpringBootTest and
>         the test annotations for testing a particular slice of your
>         application.
>    4. Command line    arguments.
>    5. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON    embedded in
>         an environment variable or system property).
>    6. ServletConfig init parameters.
>    7. ServletContext init parameters.
>    8. JNDI    attributes from java:comp/env.
>    9. Java System properties    (System.getProperties()).
>    10. OS environment variables.
>    11. A    RandomValuePropertySource that has properties only in
>          random.*.
>    12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged
>          jar
>           (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
>    13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar
>          (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
>    14. Application    properties outside of your packaged jar
>          (application.properties and    YAML variants).
>    15. Application properties packaged inside your jar
>          (application.properties and YAML variants).
>    16. @PropertySource    annotations on your @Configuration classes.
>    17. Default properties (specified by setting
>          SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).

**Edit:**
As mentioned in your edit, you are creating new object using below code

> ```
> ExampleService exampleService = new ExampleService();
> System.out.println(exampleService.getWsdlLocation())
> ```

This will create object from spring, you should using autowiring

```
@Autowired
private ExampleService exampleService ;

System.out.println(exampleService.getWsdlLocation())
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested and I'm getting: Field exampleService in ParentExampleService required a bean of type 'ExampleService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ExampleService' in your configuration.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to @Autowire that ExampleService in one of my controllers and I get error mentioned in earlier comment.

Comment: I think ExampleService object is not being created by spring , is ExampleService in a different package where your application is scanning for class (it should be same or sub package of your Application class

Comment: also, there is no spring annotation ExampleService not sure if spring will create object for WebServiceClient annotation

Comment: I've created some example code in original question which presents my problem, please take a look.